# How to insert text in url bar instead of a favicon?

Tags: url, favicon

Before anyone says it's impossible, check the address bar on this website...

https://b2bbank.com/about-us/client-communities.sn

This site has the company name in the address bar, in safari its on the right and in firefox its on the left. It's not a favicon, they have one but it shows up on other pages like Home. Anyone has a clue how to do this?

Comment: That's called EV SSL.  It has nothing to do with a favicon.

Comment: If you want something like this - buy a SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a replacement for a favicon - that's firefox's indication that they have a security certificate which has passed [extended validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). The name that displays is the name on the certificate.

Comment: I don't have an example, but I do remember seeing sites that have text  next to the URL ie. http://stackoverflow.com/ - Company Name . Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @Mia I don't believe this is possible; but, if you find an example, let me know!

Comment: Any idea if these certificates boost your SEO?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sensing that you're refering to the certificate indicator of the host site. This is a part of the public key infrastructure used on the web to be able to verify the identity of service providers on the internet. You can get one as well, but will have to pay for it, read more about it via:

(The system in it self)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure

(What a CA is and used for)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority

Long story short it's about an identity (the CA) garanteeing you / browser / system that the page you are on, is the real deal... and not a hoax, which is why you can see this "text" on most bank sites.